# Use $scope as json data with the $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to post everything that's on angular's scope service, its not much in my case but I don't want to create another object:

```
var model = angular.toJson($scope);
$http.post('/myUrl', model)
  .success(function(data) {

  });
```

However, it looks like $scope is a circular structure, because you can tell via: `Converting circular structure to JSON` when I use JSON.stringify or the string literal $Scope when I use the sample above.

Is there anyway to capture all of this data off of $scope?

This is my current hack, using underscore and underscore.string:

```
  var toJs = function(item) {
    var obj = {};
    _.each(item, function(val, key) {
      if (!_s.startsWith(key,'$')) {
        obj[key] = val;
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

then just passing:

```
  toJs($scope)
```

Comment: Isn't that `var obj = {}` creating a new object?

Comment: yes, and then copies non angular properties onto it

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create *new* object, so a possible **dirty** solutions is to remove the circular reference and every other property you don't want to POST from $scope, call `toJson`, then put all previously deleted properties back to $scope.

Comment: yeah, that's kind of like the current hack I have, just changed it to exclude anything that starts with $ which is the angular prefix. I guess that might be the only way, lets see if anyone else has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Nest a child property on $scope and call `toJson` on that.

```
<input ng-model='email'>
```

becomes

```
<input ng-model='user.email'>
```

so that

```
$http.post('/url', angular.toJson($scope.user));
```